# Fans with presumably same cooling performance but significantly different current

Tags: amperage, fan

I am looking to replace a fan in laptop. I got two candidates for a replacement. Both of them have the same Lenovo FRU number (Field Replacement Unit). From what I understand items with the same FRU must have identical characteristics (in this specific case cooling performance). However, in my case, one of the fans have current labeling of 0.5A and another one of 0.21A (both of them are DC5V). Can they have a similar cooling performance, or should I rather assume that the later one is worse? Or may it be just a matter of labeling by different manufacturers (the first one is from Delta Electronics and the second one from Panasonic)?

Comment: They probably source fans from multiple vendors with different maximum speed (hence different max current) and then program them to have similar RPM once installed. Evidently they consider this close enough for them all to have the same part part number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power consumption doesn't tell you anything about cooling performance.

For a portable device, of course the power consumption is an important parameter but there are some other important parameters, too.

Reading/comparing datasheets will not help you to judge because the manufacturers do different tests and take measurements to create/modify component-alternatives maps. These tests include durability, audible noise (not individually but while mounted on/in the actual product), rpm-vs-temperature (temp of one or more critical components), environmental tests and lifetime. None of these can be completely justified by datasheet specs.

If the manufacturer put the same number on them then they are alternatives to each other which means either can be used without risk.

If you can't be sure then contact the manufacturer.

Comment: "either can be used without risk". I looked from a different perspective. I consider if I should go with 0.21A one, because it has lower power consumption (as you say "for a portable device, of course the power consumption is an important parameter") with all others being equal. However, I tend to conclude now that the effective power consumption will be nearly the same for both of them (see user1850479's comment under the original question).

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume anything about current vs cooling performance.

You need to read the data sheet of the two fans to compare them.

If a fan is more efficient, it can offer equal cooling performance at lower current.

Comment: I couldn't find datasheets. Neither on Lenovo site nor manufacturers'